# unable to use log4j.properties from the jar in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, logging, log4j

my log4j.properties are packaged with the uber/fat application jar , here is my spark submit command

```
spark-submit --files file:log4j.properties 
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=classpath:log4j.properties  
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=classpath:log4j.properties  
--class com.myproject.Application --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn s3://myappbucket/application.jar
```

the log4j.properties are packaged and available in the jar , but when running the application they are not available to the executors , I am facing the below error , what am I missing here , how do I get the log4j.properties available to the executors/worker nodes , would someone please help

I have used the classpath:log4j.properties in the spark submit command it looks like the executors are not taking my log4j configuration changes below

```
log4j.logger.com.myproject.Application=INFO,appfile 
log4j.appender.appfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.appfile.File=${base.log.dir}/app.log
log4j.appender.appfile.MaxFileSize=200MB
log4j.appender.appfile.MaxBackupIndex=10
```

Nothing is taking in to effect and everything is getting printed on the stdout and stderr log ,instead of creating the app.log and logging in the app.log file

Answer (score 0):

The `file:` means that it is looking for the config file on the file system rather than inside the jar. you might want to try `classpath:log4j.properties`.

Comment: I have used the classpath:log4j.properties in the spark submit command it looks like the executors are not taking my log4j configuration changes below

Comment: ```log4j.logger.com.myproject.Applicationr=INFO,appfile
log4j.appender.appfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.appfile.File=${base.log.dir}/app.log
log4j.appender.appfile.MaxFileSize=200MB
log4j.appender.appfile.MaxBackupIndex=10```

Nothing is taking in to effect and everything is getting printed on the stdout and stderr log  ,instead of creating the app.log and logging in the app.log file

Comment: I'm not sure you can have "." in your identifier for the logger.

Comment: I am sorry what do you mean by "." in the identifier ? which one are you referring to ?

Comment: "com.myproject.Applicationr" is the identifier of the logger, if I read the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties) correctly I'm not sure the dots are allowed.